# How does KDE Konsole handle a SIGTERM?

Tags: c, signals, konsole

I have a particular setup:

- One `manager` program can launch and stop a program.
- One `wrapper` program which is composed of:

  - `Konsole`.
  - One program `worker` running into `Konsole`.

My problem is:

When `manager` sends `SIGTERM` to `konsole`, `konsole` seems to send `SIGKILL` to its child (since `worker` does not seems to intercept any signal).

### Testing

Worker code:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int last_sig = 0;

void sig_handler(int sig) {
    last_sig = sig;
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE * f = fopen("a.trace", "w");

    signal(SIGTERM, sig_handler);
    signal(SIGKILL, sig_handler);
    signal(SIGQUIT, sig_handler);        

    while(1) {
        if (last_sig) {
            fprintf(f, "got %d\n", last_sig);
            fflush(f);
            last_sig = 0;
        }
        else
            sleep(100); # sleep is interrupted on signal
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

#### test worker

```
gcc worker.c 

./a.out &
pkill -15 a.out
sleep 2
pkill -9 a.out
```

Contents of `a.trace` are as expected:

```
got 15
```

### problem arises when using Konsole

```
konsole -e ./a.out &

pkill -15 konsole # warning, maybe other konsole processes running
```

`a.trace` is empty, which I think is because it receives a `SIGKILL`.

- Am I right?
- How can I tell `Konsole` to translate `SIGTERM`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One partial answer is to launch a small script instead of `konsole` directly:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SIGTERM handler
on_term () {
    echo "SIGTERM got, sending to worker"
    kill -TERM $WORKERID
}

#intercept SIGTERM
trap _term SIGTERM

# launch console 
konsole --hide-menubar --hide-tabbar --nofork -e worker &

#get Konsole pid
KONSOLEID=$!

# wait for worker to be launched
sleep 1

# get worker pid 
WORKERID=$(pgrep -P $KONSOLEID worker )

echo "worker is running under pid: $WORKERID"

# wait for one child end
wait

echo "worker terminated"
```

This solution is not perfect, as it does not handle when `Konsole` is close by closing button, but it address the initial problem.